# Optimal amount of variability in predictor variables?

Tags: prediction, variability

Is there a documented reference range for how much variability is optimal for predictive models? Or how much is too little and how much is too much?

In some of my data I have a few variables that possess very little variation which makes them poor predictors (e.g CV < 5%). I also have some that have high variability which is probably also not good (e.g. CV > 50%).

I'm looking for a reference that I can cite.

Comment: This question is like asking for references concerning what size shoes are optimal: there cannot possibly be any universal answer, apart from *the size that fits,* which--although fully correct--probably wouldn't be satisfactory.  Wouldn't it be more useful to you to ask how one can tell whether the variability of a predictor is too little or too much?  And to explain to us what kind of model you have in mind and how you wish to apply it?

Comment: Sure. The inverse of the question is also fine. Any reference?

Comment: Also, any type of linear model.